# 100% line height text in scaleable div

Tags: jquery, html, responsive-design, css

I need to create a menu inside of a div that scales with the browser window. The text size adjusts depending on the size of the window (using fittext.js) and the outer DIV is always 15% of the height of the window. Since 100% line height doesn't work, what other options are there.

Also while I'm here what could be done to make the text links span 100% of the width of the containing DIV? (equal spacing between so the links cover the entire div)

jQuery options are fine if needed.

[Here is a fiddle I made with an example of my code](http://jsfiddle.net/brettlewis/CTAAA/)

HTML source

```
<nav id="navigation">
<a href="#welcome" class="nav_button"><span>Welcome</span></a>
<a href="#about" class="nav_button"><span>About</span></a>
<a href="#work" class="nav_button"><span>Work</span></a>
<a href="#contact" class="nav_button"><span>Contact</span></a>    
</nav>​
```

CSS source

```
#navigation {
width: 80%;
height: 15%;
position: fixed;
top: 5%;
left: 10%;
background: #ccc;
}
.nav_button {
height: 100%;
width: 20%;
position: relative;
display: inline-block;
text-align: center;
line-height: 100%;
}
```

​

Answer (score 0):

```
$btn = $('.nav_button');
$btn.css('line-height', $btn.height() + 'px');
```

Works fine in your example :)

Comment: Thank for the tip
I edited that a bit to work with my site. I could be off with the script I made, but It seems to work

`function lineheight() {
 var nav = $('#navigation').height();
 $('.nav_button').css({
        'line-height': nav + 'px'
    });
}  
lineheight ();
$(window).resize(lineheight);`

Comment: I'm afraid your definition of the resize event won't work... try this: 
$(window).resize(function(){ lineheight(); });​